# MEF and two instances of the same class

Tags: mef

How do I put two instances of the same class or interface into MEF?  How would I retrieve them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, any part registered with MEF uses a singleton strategy for lifetime management (one per container). This is specified with the default `CreationPolicy` of `Shared`. I think you need to be clear on exactly what you need...

**Are you wanting a new instance each time you compose?**

If so, you can add a `PartCreationPolicyAttribute` to your export:

```
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared), Export(typeof(IFoo))]
public class Foo : IFoo { }
```

Any time you compose a class using your container, you'll get a new instance of `Foo`.

**Are you wanting two independent instances at the same time?**

You'll probably want to think of an alternative pattern for getting instances of your parts. You could use an `ExportFactory` which would allow you to create new instances when you need it, e.g:

```
[Import]
public ExportFactory<IFoo> Factory { get; set; }
```

With:

```
public IFoo CreateFoo()
{
    return Factory.CreateExport().Value;
}
```

(To use `ExportFactory<T>` with non-Silverlight applications, you should download it [here](http://cid-f8b2fd72406fb218.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/blog/Composition.Initialization.Desktop.zip) - `ExportFactory<T>` never made it into .NET 4, only Silverlight).

Comment: ExportFactory is now part of .NET 4.5